# How do you block network acceess to systemd?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, netplan

How would one quarantine any systemd processes from ever using ANY network interface or resources at OS-level?

## Overview

Minimalistically, I'd like to setup a Linux gateway.  Simple NAT, forwarding home-based LAN gateway ... WITHOUT `systemd` or `systemd-networkd` accessing network-based interfaces.

### Rationale

There is no need for me to be having systemd-network or NetworkManager (or even `systemd`) to access any network interface in this minimalist mode.

### What Was Done?

I use Bind9, ISC DHCP, local `/etc/resolv.conf`, and `nftables` for all my networking needs.  Merely use the systemd for bootup sequence (as it was originally designed to do).

I disabled the following everything network-related for systemd, except systemd package itself (inspired by this [Yoon's Blog](https://www.naut.ca/blog/2018/12/12/disabling-systemd-networking/).

```bsh
systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
systemctl stop systemd-networkd.socket 
systemctl stop systemd-networkd
systemctl stop networkd-dispatcher
systemctl stop systemd-networkd-wait-online
systemctl disable systemd-networkd.socket
systemctl disable systemd-networkd
systemctl disable networkd-dispatcher
systemctl disable systemd-networkd-wait-online
apt-get remove systemd-resolvconfd
apt-get remove systemd-networkd
apt-get remove openresolv
apt-get purge netplan.io
rm /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved  #ISC now updates resolv.conf
```

and installed

```bsh
apt-get install ifupdown
```

### Issues

My problem is that `nftables` firewall really cannot block traffic at a per-process basis.

How would one quarantine all `systemd` processes from ever using ANY network interface at OS-level?  Perhaps a group resource limiter of some kind?

### Note

Please, no need for systemd flamewar.  This is an effort in retaining systemd’s original design: fastest startup.

Comment: Why not choose an appropriate distribution like [devuan](https://devuan.org/) or FreeBSD, or even OpenWRT?

Comment: That is exactly what I did to solve this “heavy-duty server” OS selection: picked Devuan distro.  I also discovered that when you yank that Ethernet cable, systemd will kill your long-startup custom daemon which is never a good thing (given our design constraints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of being downvoted, if you don't want `systemd` to access network interfaces, don't use `systemd`.

Over the years, we have seen the systemd-suite absorbing more and more functionality, and some of these require network access. As you said it yourself: it's an octopus. And the inter-dependencies of the different processes of the systemd-suite are often surprising (at least: to me). That means that if you don't go with the flow of the systemd-suite, after a few upgrades, you will need to retest and reconfigure everything.

For a real minimalistic gateway function, I would look at a busybox based system.

Comment: This is a huge downmark against `systemd` that it is no longer able to allow configurable non-network use.  I've accepted this answer ... grudgingly.

Comment: I moved back to slackware for other systemd-problems, so I sympathize.

Comment: openrc appeals to me.  But initrc via bash is king.

Answer (score 2):

You could either remove `systemd`. However there are quite a few programs depending on it.

So the other way would be to disable and stop it with `systemctl`.

Comment: Yes, but in the true spirit of Default-Deny firewalling/resourcing, how does one block a systemd process from using any network interface?  Early on, systemd was nice for its concise but fast bootup sequence, now it's an octopus.   Any way to rescope the role of systemd to just that, bootup sequence?